# Why does the other player never gets its turn in my Last Stone Game (Nim) implementation?

Tags: java

```
package HomePlace;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastStone {
    public static boolean isValidEntry(int left, int User) {
        if (left > 0 && User < 4 && left >= User) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Invalid entry!!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int userMove(int left) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("There are " + left + " stones. How many would you like? ");
        int User = input.nextInt();
        return User;
    }

    public static int computerMove(int left) {
        int cpuStones;
        cpuStones = generateStones();
        System.out.print("There are " + left + "stones. The computer takes" + cpuStones + " stones");
        return cpuStones;
    }

    public static int generateStones() {
        Random sr = new Random();
        int gstones = sr.nextInt(2) + 1;
        return gstones;
    }

    public static void playLastStone(int UserOrCpu) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (UserOrCpu % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("The Computer beats the User!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The User beats the Computer!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int left = r.nextInt(16) + 15;
        int UserOrCpu = 1, User = 1, temp;
        while (true) {
            if (UserOrCpu % 2 == 1) {
                User = userMove(left);
                if (isValidEntry(left, User)) {
                    if (left == User) {
                        playLastStone(UserOrCpu);
                        break;
                    }
                    left -= User;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                computerMove(left);
                temp = computerMove(left);
                if (left <= temp) {
                    playLastStone(UserOrCpu);
                    break;
                } else {
                    left -= temp;
                }
            }
        }
        UserOrCpu += 1;
    }
}
```

My computer player *cpu* never takes its turn in my implementation of the [Last Stone game or Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

I found similar questions but none helped with solving my problem.

I debugged my code line by line but couldn't figure out why my second `} else {` in my `main` method is never executed?

```
                    left -= User;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else { // why is it never executed?
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this code should be doing. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: When you say it "...went through `}else{`...: there are **two** `}else{` in that code snippet.  Which one did you mean?

Comment: Why should it go further, `left -= User` is the last line in the while loop for that path?

Comment: You should clean up the code, there are unused local variables.

Comment: This is the classic [NIM game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)

Comment: Sorry it's a bit messy.. I started Java not so long ago.. I'm even confused by my own code haha

Answer (score 2):

In your given code, your `main` method actually reduces itself to

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int left = r.nextInt(16) + 15;
        int userOrCpu = 1, user;
        while (true) {
            user = userMove(left);
            if (isValidEntry(left, user)) {
                if (left == user) {
                    playLastStone(userOrCpu);
                    break;
                }
                left -= user;
            }
        }
    }
```

And so it's now clear that your computer player `cpu` never gets its turn.

The problem is that your `UserOrCpu += 1;` assignment isn't in the right scope, and so doesn't have any effect.

The "fixed" `main` method should look like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int left = r.nextInt(16) + 15;
        int UserOrCpu = 1, User = 1, temp;
        while (true) {
            if (UserOrCpu % 2 == 1) {
                User = userMove(left);
                if (isValidEntry(left, User)) {
                    if (left == User) {
                        playLastStone(UserOrCpu);
                        break;

                    }
                    left -= User;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                computerMove(left);
                temp = computerMove(left); // executes computer move a 2nd time?
                if (left <= temp) {
                    playLastStone(UserOrCpu);
                    break;

                } else {
                    left -= temp;
                }
            }
            UserOrCpu += 1;
        }
    }
```

***Hint:*** Get yourself an IDE (like IntelliJ) for writing code. Such a code editor will indicate "obvious" problems with your code immediately.

Comment: So I fixed my code with your new code, but now the computer gets two turns; After the line computerMove(left), it goes down to "temp = computerMove(left)" and then that code prints computer move again. I only put temp because i was going put computerMove(left) as a int.

Comment: @LogicNAME It's still ___your code___ as you've given it in your question description; ___including the 2 invocations of the ``computerMove(left)`` method___. I don't understand why it's a surprise to you that the computer player gets two turns... after all, it _is_ what you implemented. If you don't want that then only keep the ``temp = computerMove(left);`` statement and remove the other. // I answered your question by showing you what needed to be changed so that you can overcome the point where you got stuck. However, this doesn't mean that I fix up all your code or implement Nim for you.